# Scipy 3D Delaunay. Different results when translating the set of points

Tags: python, scipy, delaunay

I thought that given a set of points, the 3D Delaunay network would be unique. But moving all the points (without changing the relative distances) gives a different result.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay

points = np.array([ [-0.6, -0.1, -1.5], [0, 0, 0], [-1,-1,-1],[1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 2], [0, 1.1, -1]])
points = points+[0,5,0] #for translation

tri = Delaunay(points)
```

I have compared the results and the connection matrices, and they differ.

**Case 0. No translation.** Connection matrix.

```
array([[0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1.],
       [0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1.],
       [0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0.]])
```

Image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/482RZ.png)

**Case 1. Translating 5 units in y-direction.** Connection matrix.

```
array([[0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1.],
       [1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1.],
       [0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1.],
       [1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0.]])
```

Image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzMqV.png)

Any idea why they are different?

The connection matrix is computed this way:

```
matrix = np.zeros((len(points),len(points))

for triangle in tri.simplices:
    for i in range(4): 
        point_initial = triangulo[i] 
        point_final = triangulo[(i+1)%4] 

        if matrix[point_initial,point_final] == 1:
            continue
        
        matrix[point_initial,point_final] = 1
        matrix[point_final,point_initial] = 1
```

You can see `tri.simplices` are also different in both cases:

```
array([[1, 4, 3, 2],
       [1, 4, 5, 2],
       [1, 4, 5, 3],
       [1, 0, 3, 2],
       [1, 0, 5, 2],
       [1, 0, 5, 3]], dtype=int32)

array([[1, 4, 3, 2],
       [1, 4, 5, 2],
       [1, 4, 5, 3],
       [0, 1, 3, 2],
       [0, 1, 5, 2],
       [0, 1, 5, 3]], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: How do you get your connection matrix ? Cause when I use the `tri.simplices` to draw the connection figure, there is no difference before and after translation

Comment: Hi @HMH1013, I edit the original post to answer your question.

Comment: Actually, the problem is when you calculate the connection matrix, your points are in  3D, so the connections are not 4. It's not like in 2D the connection is a triangle, in 3D it's like a Triangular pyramid. The number the connection is 6. For example the first line of `tri.simplices`, the connections are `(1, 4), (4, 3), (3, 2), (2, 1)` and `(1, 3) , (4, 2)`, which you forgot.

Comment: Thanks @HMH1013, that's it. Maybe you want to write it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@geofisue Thanks for the proposition for writing the answer.

As I described in the comment, the reason for the problem is that when transitioning from a 2D plane point to a 3D solid point, the simplices in the triangulation change from a triangle to a triangular pyramid.

[image: the triangulation 2D]

[image: the triangulation 3D]

So the number of the connections change from 3 to 6.

Then I modified the function for calculating the connection matrix, which can be used in nD:

```
import itertools
matrix = np.zeros((len(points),len(points)))
    
for triangle in tri.simplices:
    connections = list(itertools.combinations(triangle, 2))
    for connection in connections:
        point_initial = connection [0] 
        point_final = connection[1]

        if matrix[point_initial,point_final] == 1:
            continue
        
        matrix[point_initial,point_final] = 1
        matrix[point_final,point_initial] = 1
```

The full codes:

```
import itertools
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

points = np.array([ [-0.6, -0.1, -1.5], [0, 0, 0], [-1,-1,-1],[1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 2], [0, 1.1, -1]])
points_trans = points+[0,5,0] #for translation

tri = Delaunay(points)
tri_trans = Delaunay(points_trans)



def get_connection_matrix(points):
    matrix = np.zeros((len(points),len(points)))
        
    for triangle in tri.simplices:
        connections = list(itertools.combinations(triangle, 2))
        for connection in connections:
            point_initial = connection [0] 
            point_final = connection[1]
    
            if matrix[point_initial,point_final] == 1:
                continue
            
            matrix[point_initial,point_final] = 1
            matrix[point_final,point_initial] = 1
    return matrix

matrix =  get_connection_matrix(points)
matrix_trans =  get_connection_matrix(points_trans)

print(np.array_equal(matrix, matrix_trans))
```

The result :

```
> True
```